# Joomla: Zoo Component Edit Submissions

Tags: php, joomla, zoo

I am developing a Joomla site and I am using Zoo component in it. I have created the frontend submission and it is working. Now I want to edit the submissions. I have created the "My Submissions" and it is also working. But when I click on the edit button of submission I get a blank page with just header and footer and no form to edit.

What am I doing wrong? I have followed the documentation for Zoo but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell me what version you are using. I have used Zoo in many projects but I didn't find such problem. I would you to try with latest zoo package & confirm. Even if this won't work. Check with your third party extensions or template which might break the Zoo edit functionality. Best luck...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an "edit.php" and a "submissions.php" file in your application template.

See here: http://yootheme.com/support/question/71022

Having these files in your item renderer will make sure that your template layouts are then configurable in the backend.

It is important too that you have set up the editable layout, with all the editable elements in your view.